# convert element of 2D list into string python

Tags: python, list

I have a 2D list containing all integers. I want to convert all integer into string:

```
L = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]

L = [['1','2','3','4','5'],['6','7','8','9','10']]  # convert into string.
```

Now print them out like following format:

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
>
> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10

I tried using these codes:

```
final_out = [i for i in final_out str(ii) for ii in i]
```

It does not works.

Comment: You need to clarify what your desired output format is. Would you like a string? Would you like the items of your lists printed?

Comment: My desired output format is, first line would be: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5, second line would be:  6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` function for this:

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
>>> L = [map(str, l) for l in L]  # Convert into list of 'str'
>>> L   
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
>>> for l in L:
...     print ' -> '.join(l)
... 
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
```

Simpler way to write the above code is:

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
>>> for l in L:
...     print ' -> '.join(map(str, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
print("\n".join(" -> ".join(str(num) for num in sub) for sub in L))
```

Output:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
```

Since I used `str(num)`, you can just keep `L` the same.  That is, you don't need to convert them to integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that using `nested loop`:

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
>>> new_L = [[str(j) for j in i] for i in L]
>>> new_L
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
>>> for i in new_L:
    print ' -> '.join(i)


1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
>>>
```